# Simple multi-colored textarea based editor

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to colorize textarea code for a split HTML/CSS/JS/Result editing tool. In this example, I want tags to be one color and all other text - another color.

A monospace font is always used.

So I decided to separate the tags text from the rest and put each part into its own textarea on top of the main one. The missing half (regular text for tags and tag text for the rest) is replaced by spaces, to keep everything in the correct position.

Below is a working snippet (I did only simple typing tests).

I have a couple of questions:

1. Are there any major drawbacks to this approach? Will the end user be cut off off some common text operation in the textarea?
2. I use the following regexp to separate tags from the rest of the text:

   ```
   elem.value.match(/(<[^<>]+>)|([\s\S]*?(?=(<[^<>]+>)))|((?<=(<[^<>]+>))[\s\S]*)/g);
   ```

the idea here is to match either a tag `(<[^<>]+>)` or something that is followed by a tag or something that follows one.

Is it possible to make this expression simpler?

Ideally, for it to say capture "a tag" or "not a tag", I have difficulty defining the latter.

```js
const TAB = '  ';

const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

const [main, tag, txt] = [get('main'), get('tag'), get('txt')];

const colorizeHTML = evt => { 
    const elem = evt.target;
    const arr = elem.value.split(/(?!^)(?=<[^<>]+>)|(?<=<[^<>]+>)(?!$)/);
    if (!arr) return;
    let [str_tag, str_txt] = ['', ''];
    arr.forEach(s => {
        const repl = s.replace(/[^\n ]/g, '\xa0');
        if (s[0] == '<' && s[s.length - 1] == '>') {
            str_tag += s;
            str_txt += repl;
        } else {
            str_tag += repl;
            str_txt += s;
        }
    });
    tag.value = str_tag;
    txt.value = str_txt;
}

const onKeyDownDefault = evt => {
    if (evt.key == "Tab") {
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, TAB);
    }
}

const onScroll = evt => {
    const scr = evt.target.scrollTop;
    tag.scrollTop = scr;
    txt.scrollTop = scr;
}

main.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownDefault);
main.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

['input', 'keyup', 'mouseup', 'drop', 'paste'].forEach(nm => { main.addEventListener(nm, colorizeHTML) });

main.value = 'Chapter 12<div id="sec1">\n<div>Standard Curves</div>\n<div id="tot1"></div>\n<button id="btn1">Toggle points</button>\n</div>';
colorizeHTML({ target: main });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #999;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 170px;
}

#tag, #txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#main, #tag, #txt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  resize: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 3px;
}

#main {
  border: solid 1px #666;
  background: rgba(8, 15, 32, 1.0);
  caret-color: #91d6db;
}

#main::selection {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 128, 0.15);
}

#main::-moz-selection {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 128, 0.15);
}

#tag {
    color: #4576e6;
}

#txt {
    color: #9bc6ca;
}

.clean_scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.clean_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<textarea id="main" class="clean_scroll"></textarea>
<textarea id="tag" class="clean_scroll"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" class="clean_scroll"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see one MAIN drawback ... when you hit tab, you switch between texareas and you can write directly to `tag` or `txt` without any event, making a mess of duplicated colors in the same place and once when I was hitting random keys it started to write black (don't know when)

Comment: I added a code to handle tab in place

Comment: Trapping the focus inside an element kills a11y. You need to provide at least functionality (and an `aria-label` that explains this) for `esc` key to exit the textarea for non-mouse users.